# security of app service for bot built for Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a bot for Teams so that users can get information of my backend service. To achieve that, I need build an app service as a middle layer to connect teams and my backend service. In such a case, I am wondering how to make my middle layer app service more secure such that nobody can call the app service except the messages from Teams. Or is it not necessary to consider such protection?

Teams ----> middle layer APP ---> backend service

Comment: You can allow only ms team users by AD privilege's through grahp api and middle layer is look like your bot app and their you need to write your logic.

Comment: @derek Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: I am not clear what is your answer. What is AD privilege? And I am not using graph api at all in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @RajeeshMenoth comments

You can allow only ms team users by AD privilege's through grahp api and middle layer is look like your bot app and their you need to write your logic.